# Image source can't resolve

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, vue.js

I try to show image but it can't show , it goes to url
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mywedding/public/assets/images/cpp-test.jpg
but its return not found so i change from this,
here code from resources/js/views/components/Mempelai.vue

```
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
.m-name {
    font-family: Greenlight Script;
}

.pl {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-image: url('/mywedding/public/assets/images/mask.png');
    -webkit-mask-image:  url('/mywedding/public/assets/images/mask.png');
    mask-size: 200px;
    -webkit-mask-size: 200px;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-position: center;
    -webkit-mask-position: center;
    background-image: url('/mywedding/public/assets/images/cpp-test.jpg');
}
```

to this

```
 mask-image: url('assets/images/gallery/mask.png');
 -webkit-mask-image:  url('assets/images/gallery/mask.png');
```

but it turn error when i run `npm run dev`
the error msg

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve 'assets/images/gallery/mask.png' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vc\wedding-digital-invitation-master\resources\js\views\components'
    at finishWithoutResolve (C:\xampp\htdocs\vc\wedding-digital-invitation-master\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:309:18)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\vc\wedding-digital-invitation-master\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:386:15
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\vc\wedding-digital-invitation-master\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:435:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\xampp\htdocs\vc\wedding-digital-invitation-master\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\vc\wedding-digital-invitation-master\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:435:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\xampp\htdocs\vc\wedding-digital-invitation-master\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
```

i try to implement solution from internet using

```
./../../assets/images/gallery/mask.png
```

but it still no work

here laravel folder
https://github.com/salmanagustian/wedding-digital-invitation

Comment: `/public` should not appear in a Laravel url, it is/should be the "DocumentRoot" of your project.

Comment: so i need to move asset from public to resources folder?

Comment: No,that's not what I said. If you serve your project from the "mywedding" folder, your URL should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/images/cpp-test.jpg`.

Comment: yes, i already change  from mask-image: ```url('/mywedding/public/assets/images/mask.png');``` to ```mask-image: url('assets/images/gallery/mask.png');``` but its go error cant resolve that path. so i tried ```url('./../../assets/images/gallery/mask.png');``` and still error